# What is the mystery text appearing in the search box

Tags: support, search

What does the mystery text like **user:328460** appearing in the search box mean ?

[image]

Comment: I've also seen "node/add" mysteriously added to the search box on the home page as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, when you view someone's profile the site puts `user:<USER ID>` in the search box automatically.

You can use the automatically generated text to help quickly search for the user's posts that contain a certain keyword:

- Click in the textbox, making sure the cursor is at the end of the text
- Press <kbd>Space</kbd> then add your additional search keywords
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to begin the search

If viewing your own profile it still behaves the same way.

Answer (score 4):

It [means you're searching](https://superuser.com/help/searching) for all posts from that user.